# Expect script failed with "spawn id not open" when calling "expect eof"

Tags: tcl, expect, eof

I am trying to call an expect script from bash and have it return exit code in case of e.g. Connection Timeout.

Basically the bash script is calling expect like this:

```
if [[ -f $1 ]]; then
    do something
else
    script.exp $device
    # here I want to evaluate the exit code but it is always 0
fi
```

I found some previous questions about it and that the right way to catch exit codes is:

```
expect eof
catch wait result
exit [lindex \$result 3].
```

The expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

exp_internal 1
log_user 1
set timeout -1
set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
set prompt "sftp>";

if { $hostname == "blah" } {
        set username "user1"
        set password "pass1"
} else {
        set username "user2"
        set password "pass2"
}

spawn sftp $username@$hostname "-o ConnectTimeout=3"

expect {
    "timeout" {
        puts "A timeout occured"
        exp_continue
    }
    "password:" {
         send "$password\r"
         exp_continue
    }
    "sftp>" {
         send "cd cfg\n"
         expect $prompt
         send "get * /some/dir/$hostname\n"
         expect $prompt
         send "get running-config /some/dir/$hostname-config\n"
         expect $prompt
         send "exit\r";
         exp_continue
    }
}
expect eof
catch wait result
exit [lindex \$result 3]
```

When I just test the expect script to see what happens, I get this error:

```
expect: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"expect eof"
```

I've tried moving expect eof around but it does not change the behavior. It states that the spawned process id is not open, which I guess is correct as it has exited with Timed Out/Connection closed?

Comment: The `expect eof` should become a clause of the `expect` just above it.

Comment: I actually already moved the "expect eof" up into the expect but that gives me expected integer but got ""
    while executing
"exit [lindex \$result 3]", so there is no exit code provided in the exit there either.

Comment: You have to get rid of the backslash. So: `exit [lindex $result 3]`. The backslash would be needed for people who complicate things by putting the expect script in a here-document. You went the sane way by using a file for the expect script. But then you shouldn't escape the dollar sign.

Comment: if you write shell scripts, take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/), its default behaviors are more user friendly than Expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `exp_continue` after `send "exit\r"`, otherwise EOF will be consumed by the `expect { ... }` block and another `expect eof` would fail.
2. Change `lindex \$result 3` to `lindex $result 3` as in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

(Incorporating the previous comments)
Add it into the previous expect command, but with no body:

```
expect {
    timeout   {...}
    password: {...}
    sftp>     {...}
    eof
}
wait result
if {[lindex $result 2] == 0} {
    exit [lindex $result 3]
} else {
    error "system error: errno [lindex $result 3]"
}
```